# Determine what child node's change fires "onChildChanged" method in firebase with android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sONyv.png) is my firebase structure

Here is my code fore the firebase

```
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    bookingRef = database.getReference("booking");


    query = bookingRef.orderByChild("studentID").equalTo("S00001");
    query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Booking myBooking = dataSnapshot.getValue(Booking.class);
            addBookingRow(myBooking, dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
              //here it is fired when the alarset value is changed
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String tag = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            removeBookingRow(tag);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Each Booking node has several `child nodes(?)` which are classID, studentID, attended, alarmType

As you can see, I have got query for getting nodes having certain student ID.

Then, i have added `addChildEventListener` for the ordered nodes.

So, when any of the **child nodes** of the booking node changes, the `onChildChanged` method is fired, and it gives me the data snapshot for the booking node having child node change.

Here I want to know what child node changed. Like I want to know if the `onChildChanged` method is fired on the change of ClassID.

It is because I want to implement different behaviour based on change of each **child node**

Do i have to set some listener for each child node? or ..

Can you guys give me solutions?

I am developing in android studio

thanks